# How to open Pidgin Buddy List if chat window is opened/minimized

Tags: 16.04, pidgin, pidgin-sipe

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Pidgin with SIPE plugin.
If I open a chat window and then close the Buddy List, I can not open the Buddy List again as long as I do not close all chat windows and then click the pidgin icon in my sidebar. If I click the pidgin icon, the chat window gets opened and I can not find a way to get access to the Buddy List again once its closed and a chat window is open/minimized.

So my question is, how can I open the Buddy List if a chat window is already opened?

Comment: If you have set up your system to show the comunications icon in the tray (the envelope), click on the Pidgin icon in it's menu. It was that easy for me.
If that doesn't work have a look at the "Related" questions. The "Pidgin doesn't show buddy list" has lots of other ways I was too lazy to try.